# Intersect using custom function in f#

Tags: .net, linq, f#

I have two lists. The first is a list of structured records that have an Id property where the Id is a string wrapper. The second is a simple list of strings.

I need to find all the records in the first list whose Id is represented in the second set.

In c# this would be trivial:

```
var intersect = list1.Where(x => list2.Contains(x.Id.ToString()))
```

Maybe there are more efficient ways to get the intersection but c# with linq makes it very easy to get the required output.

I'm fairly new to f# but it seems like this is a non-trivial operation in f#. Linq in f# doesn't support the lambda comparator function (as far as I can see) and the built in filter function seems to rely on a direct comparison between the entities in the two lists (its not easy to specify a custom comparator).

I've tried the following:

```
list1 |> List.filter(fun x -> List.contains (x.Id.ToString() list2))
```

... but this gives the following compiler error:

```
This expression was expected to have type
    'bool'    
but here has type
    ''a list -> bool'
```

I am really hoping that someone is going to tell me that I'm being dumb and there is a really easy way to do this in f#... please!

**ANSWER**

It turns out that I had messed up my syntax. I **think** that the parentheses below are required to force *x.Id.ToString()* to be evaluated first but the parentheses around the parameters to List.contains aren't required

```
list1 |> List.filter(fun x -> List.contains (x.Id.ToString()) list2)
```

Comment: Your parens are in the wrong place still ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In F#, function arguments are separated by *spaces*, not commas, and the parentheses around each argument are optional. You do not have parentheses around the whole argument list - that would indicate a tuple.

You have written:

```ml
list1 |> List.filter(fun x -> List.contains (x.Id.ToString(), list2))
```

But you probably meant this:

```ml
list1 |> List.filter (fun x -> List.contains (x.Id.ToString()) list2)
```

---

Complete example (put in an `.fsx` file):

```ml
type Foo =
  {
    Id : string
  }

let list1 =
  [
    { Id = "a" }
    { Id = "b" }
    { Id = "x" }
  ]

let list2 =
  [
    "a"
    "b"
    "c"
  ]

let list3 =
  list1 |> List.filter (fun x -> List.contains (x.Id.ToString()) list2)

printfn "%A" list3

// [{ Id = "a" }; { Id = "b" }]
```

Comment: yes - you are right. However, correcting the comma (as I have done now in my original question) still gives the same compiler error.

Comment: @MattAustin You will need to share some more code I think. I have added a complete example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Based on your snippet I see that I've screwed up the parentheses in the function. I'll update my question with the (very simple) fix.